# Izenda csv report issue

Tags: sql, .net, csv, export-to-csv, fputcsv

The CSV file size is 29 MB in Izenda report. I can able to download the file through bulk csv option configured but not in default csv. Is there any file size download limitation for csv. Please tell what is the exact root cause for this. Further, is there any fix or alternative to download the report in existing csv option.

Note : Currrently there are around 80,000 records being downloaded..This may increase in time.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there is file size limit in izenda for the normal CSV Download.
You need to use **Bulk CSV Download** when data is >80,000 records.

To Enable Bulk CSV use the Following in the code or config:

```
AdHocSettings.OutputTypes["BULKCSV"].Hidden = false;
```

Answer (score 1):

I would definitely recommend reviewing some of the Izenda Wiki materials, as they could be very helpful. Also, feel free to reach out to support@izenda.com for guidance on any questions you might have.

If you're up to date on maintenance update to the latest build:
http://www.izenda.com/update-your-izenda-version/

Some CSV fixes were just made:
http://wiki.izenda.us/Release-Notes#6.9.0.5-(September-22,-2015)

I'd take a look at:
http://wiki.izenda.us/API/CodeSamples/UseBulkCSV
http://wiki.izenda.us/API/CodeSamples/ExportLimit
http://wiki.izenda.us/FAQ/Formatting/How-do-I-Add-bulk-CSV-to-the-report-viewer
http://wiki.izenda.us/Guides/Toolbar-Buttons

The dault export limit is somewhere in the 60k-70k row range.

In essence if you're using Bulk CSV, it should replace the regular CSV option automatically. Bulk CSV is only limited by IIS/Web Configurations.

Use the ExportLimit setting to extend the total number of allowed rows in all exports. Be careful about how high you set this of course, and make sure that the row count and your SQL Timeouts settings play nice together. This setting effects all export types including Bulk CSV.

Outside of Izenda, make sure to check your IIS settings for export/import file size limitations.

Here's a good serverfault article: 
https://serverfault.com/questions/458505/iis7-how-to-configure-server-to-serve-large-gbs-files

Let me (or Izenda) know if this helps!